# How to add a cookie in facebook webdriver 1.3.0

Tags: php, facebook, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I try to add a cookie like this, just like in [example.php](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/blob/community/example.php) (line 22).

```
// adding cookie
$driver->manage()->deleteAllCookies();
$cookie = new Cookie('cookie_name', 'cookie_value');
$driver->manage()->addCookie($cookie);
$cookies = $driver->manage()->getCookies();
print_r($cookies);
```

But I get:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Facebook\WebDriver\Cookie' not
>   found in C:\xampp\htdocs\selenium_standalone\example.php:19 Stack
>   trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\selenium_standalone\example.php on line 19

This is line 19: `$cookie = new Cookie('cookie_name', 'cookie_value');`

I am using `selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar`

Comment: I already use the API.

Comment: No your not. The API doesn't use Cookies.

Comment: Then why are there plenty of Cookie functions in the API : https://facebook.github.io/php-webdriver/latest/Facebook/WebDriver/WebDriverOptions.html#method_addCookie

Comment: Because that is not the API. The API you can read about on https://developers.facebook.com/docs

Comment: Do you know what the facebook webdriver is?

Answer (score 3):

As far, as I see, you use `addCookie` method with wrong parameter. Try something like this:

```
$driver->manage()->addCookie(['name' => 'cookie_name', 'value' => 'cookie_value']);
```

Also, you may get an error as:

> Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnknownServerException: : Failed to set the 'cookie' property on 'Document': Cookies are disabled inside 'data:' URLs.

In this case you should navigate to some page in needed domain and then add cookie.

Hope this helps.